# Database connection error in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2014

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and have installed MS SQL Server 2014. I am trying to generate my database from a model (edmx) but I get the following error (screenshot attached):

[image: Connection error]

In the edmx.sql file, is written:

> -- Entity Designer DDL Script for SQL Server 2005, 2008, 2012 and Azure
>
> ---

I can see that 2014 version is missing from this generated file, and seems that the program tries to connect to the 2012 version .. how can I avoid this and manage visual studio tu use the 2014 version of MS SQL Server?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What Sql Server data tools are you using?
Have you tried newer version of it:
[Microsoft® SQL Server Data Tools for SQL Server® 2014 CTP2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40850)

Comment: This might be the problem.. I am performing the Sql Server data tools update (takes some time) and I'll come back with the answer, whether it works or it doesn't

Comment: unfortunately I get the same error.. Do I need to specify somewhere in my project that I want to use the newest version or something like that?

Comment: Yes, in the project settings (right click on project->Properties->Target platform)

Comment: Target platform is set to be the newest one.. I mean, maybe there is a place where a I can specify which version of SQL Server to be use?